# Matlab MCR in ubuntu Amazon ec2

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

After installing MCR on Ubuntu, I cant run my code. The following is the error that I get. I tried googling but cant solve the problem.

```
./run_HPC_Location_Replacer.sh /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83
```

Setting up environment variables

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH is .:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/sys/os/glnxa64
```

An Error has occurred while trying to initialize the MCR.

> The error is: Fatal error loading library /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64/libmwmclbase.so Error: libXt.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   Error:mclmcr initialization failed

Comment: Did you ever get to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I run into the same problem on my EC2 instance, and seems like it is missing the package `lixbt6`.

The problem got fixed after I did `sudo apt-get install libxt6`

Comment: This should be a comment!